# React native App fails to launch after buid

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

guys, I'm totally new here and I'm hoping I really get the help I need 
I built an apk package with eas build -p android --profile test, the build was successful. App installed successfully on mobile but it fails to open. once clicked, it just opens then immediately closes back.
I’m all new to expo and development in general.

---

I saw a documentation to run the app via npx expo start --no-dev --minify ; as this mimics production mode in local server. I did that and It returns a “uncaught error: java.lan.exception:failed to load all assests” I reloaded like 4 times and app opens fine after that. And does not bring the error again when I rebundle app.
However I have observed it brings the error (java.lang.exception:failed to load all assests) once everytime I stop and restart the expo server.
But app doesn't launch at all when I build to standalone.

Please help here, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I solved it

Follow the steps.

```
1.) Turn on USB Tethering & USB Debugging Mode in your mobile.

2.) Connect your mobile to your laptop through USB.

3.) Verify the connection options on your device, I just added WIFI bridge / I assume i the same as wifi debugging and then, restarted the device and run expo and it worked.
```

Above solution is worked for me.